# Project Euler #1: Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x

> Challenge Description:
>
> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
>   <sub>[Source](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)</sub>

I want to receive advice on my code.

```
total_sum = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if (i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0):
        total_sum = total_sum+i
print total_sum
```

Comment: Does `in range(1000)` really mean `1...999` (remember the question asks for **below** 1000)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> total_sum = 0
> for i in range(1000):
>     if (i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0):
>         total_sum = total_sum+i
> print total_sum
> ```

You should leave your numbers, variables and operators some space to breathe by adding some horizontal space between them which improves readability a lot.

```
total_sum = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0):
        total_sum = total_sum + i
print total_sum
```

As natural numbers aren't explictly defined containing `0` you could also use the two-parameter form of the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function and specify the `start` parameter like so

```
total_sum = 0
for i in range(1, 1000):
    if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0):
        total_sum = total_sum + i
print total_sum
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your second point, and I'm less sure OP did. For example, you mention a `start` parameter, but the following code example doesn't contain this word. Maybe you could make more clear what you mean.

Comment: Is it more clear now ?

Comment: A bit. I guess what's throwing me off is that you've written "*a* start parameter", as if they were several "start parameters" and you could choose one of them; but you mean *the* first parameter of the range function, which is called "start". Ideally there would also be a link to the documentation so that one could immediately see the different forms of the function.

Comment: I don't do python, I just googled about range() and saw on could use the  optional start parameter. I will rephrase my answer.

Comment: Sorry your edit had been rejected by the community because I edited at the same time. I used your edit now.

Comment: Just a note, since the Natural numbers is very frequently defined to include 0, I don't think the last change is actually an improvement aside from a gain in "efficiency."

Comment: In the same way natural numbers are also frequently defined not to include 0. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number

Comment: There's also [this](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3256), where they say they'll explicitly state which set they're working with.  However, for this problem it doesn't matter since `0` is never a multiple of 3 or 5.  In fact, you could start your range at 3 and call it good based on the same premise - and then we don't have to quibble over how wrong you are to exclude 0 from the natural numbers ;)

Comment: I just wanted to disagree with your "breathing room" suggestion for operators. In my opinion, it's often better for readability to group some operations without whitespace, and indeed [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) discusses that.

Answer (score 23):

You don't need iteration at all for this problem.

Consider; the sum of all numbers from 1 to n is equal to n*(n+1)/2.  Also the sum of all numbers less than n that divides d equals d times the sum of all numbers less than n/d.

So the sum of all numbers less than 1000 that divides 3 is

```
3*floor(999/3)*(floor(999/3)+1)/2
```

Likewise the sum of all numbers less than 1000 that divides 5 is

```
5*floor(999/5)*(floor(999/5)+1)/2
```

Adding the two numbers would overcount though.  Since the numbers that divides both 3 and 5 would get counted twice.  The numbers that divides both 3 and 5 is precisely the numbers that divides `3*5/gcd(3,5)=15/1=15`.

The sum of all numbers less than 1000 that divides 15 is

```
15*floor(999/15)*(floor(999/15)+1)/2
```

So the final result is that the sum of all numbers less than 1000 that divides either 3 or 5 equals:

```
  3 * (floor(999/3)  *  (floor(999/3)+1))/2
+ 5 * (floor(999/5)  *  (floor(999/5)+1))/2
-15 * (floor(999/15) * (floor(999/15)+1))/2
```

Comment: Instead of calling `floor`, you can use the integer division operator, `//`. Also, the relevant concept is the very useful to remember [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: I've learned that this is the trick for most (all?) of the Project Euler problems I've worked on.  They usually have a fairly obvious brute force solution and then a straightforward "more obscure" solution based on a math algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

Define a function to solve more general problems:

```
def divisible_by_under(limit, divs):
    return (i for i in  range(limit) if any(i % div == 0 for div in divs))
```

This works for any limit and any divisor and is inside an easy to test function.

```
print(sum(divisible_by_under(1000, (3, 5))))
```

Comment: @CoolGuy should work with pithon 2 too

Comment: Hmm. I thought that putting parentheses around the print will raise some error...

Comment: @CoolGuy almost.. not using parens in python 3 for print is an error

Comment: @CoolGuy Unnecessary parens are fine in any version of Python, and they don't need any surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

You could use list comprehension, to save a few lines, but it does exactly the same as yours:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0]))
```

Comment: I love this form best, and just wanted to add that the sum function takes a generator expression as well, so you don't need the square brackets: `print(sum(i for i in range(1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0))`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to type this out fully:

```
total_sum = total_sum+i
```

Python has a `+=` operator, basically shorthand for what you have above. Take what's on the left of the operator and add the result of what's on the right.

```
total_sum += i
```

Also when in Python2.7 it's recommended you use `for i in xrange(1000)`. `range` will immediately create a full list of numbers it stores in memory, while `xrange` is a generator that produces each number as it's needed. The performance difference is helpful for large ranges but it's generally a good habit to keep.

Comment: Be careful however, because `xrange` is bad advice for Python 3.

Comment: @Nayuki, a link to *why* it's bad advice would be helpful.

Comment: @Wildcard Python 3 doesn't have `xrange`, because `range` is already a generator. I presume that's what they were getting at.

Answer (score 4):

This code is extremely inefficient. Using some basic math we can reduce runtime to constant time complexity. For any `n` (in this case 1000), we can predict the number of numbers `< n` and divisible by 3 or 5:

- numbers divisible by 3: lowerbound(n / 3)
- numbers divisible by 5: lowerbound(n / 5)

The sum of all numbers divisible by 3 or 5 can then be predicted using eulers formula:
the sum of all numbers from 1 to `n` is `n(n + 1)/2`. Thus the sum of all numbers `n` divisible by 3 is:

```
int div_3 = (n / 3)
int sum_div_3 = div_3 * (div_3 + 1) / 2 * 3
```

Now there's only one point left: all numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 appear twice in the sum (in the sum of all numbers divisible by 3 and the sum of all numbers divisble by 5). Since 3 and 5 are prim, all numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 are multiples of 15.

```
int sum_div3_5(int n)
    int div_3 = (n - 1) / 3 , 
        div_5 = (n - 1) / 5 , 
        div_15 = (n - 1) / 15

    int sum = div_3 * (div_3 + 1) * 3 / 2 + //sum of all numbers divisible by 3
              div_5 * (div_5 + 1) * 5 / 2 - //sum of all numbers divisible by 5
              div_15 * (div_15 + 1) * 15 / 2

    return sum
```

I can't provide python code though.